# Diagnosing possible SMPS feedback loop failure

Tags: power-supply, led, switch-mode-power-supply, negative-feedback

I work in a theatre and I'm looking for some guidance on how to solve an issue regarding a 24V power supply in one of my LED lights. The model is a Chauvet SlimPAR QUAD 12 IRC, to be exact, consisting of 4 sets of LED channels(red, green, blue and amber). With budgets as tight as ever there is a renewed interest in getting as much low power LED kit fixed as possible.

The fault first came to our attention when the light began constantly flickering and had a ticking sound emanating from inside, regardless of what output levels we set it to. I have taken it apart and found that some of the electrolytic capacitors within the power supply had bulged and leaked.

After replacing the 3 x 35V 1000uF and 1 x 400V 120uF I now find myself in a position where all colour channels (red, green, blue, amber) work correctly at full output.
Once any colour (except red) is dimmed to around <40% of its full output the flicker returns and I hear ticking once again, albeit at a lower level this time.

It has been suggested to me that the issue lays somewhere in the feedback circuit on the secondary side. The [replacement capacitors](https://cpc.farnell.com/panasonic/eeufm1v102/capacitor-radial-1000uf-35v/dp/CA07431?CMP=i-ddd7-00001003) I have used are supposedly "low ESR" but as the issue is still present I am unsure what to investigate next.

Any help or links to further guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

Admittedly one of the capacitors has been soldered on a little wonky but the connection is good. I am aware this is a cheap and nasty power supply but unfortunately there is no money for a complete replacement and searches for circuit specs have been unsuccessful. I am tinkering with this as a hobby in an attempt to extend the light's lifetime.

Many thanks!

Comment: How much is your time worth I wonder?

Comment: A good point raised. Admittedly I am bordering on the point of diminished returns here which is why I stress this has crossed into being more of a hobby than trying to solve it on work time.

Comment: Is your hobby to be defined by fixing cheap (and probably poorly designed) light fixtures. I'm just saying this because you might not get from your "hobby" what you might really desire. Trying to fix poorly designed stuff just gets you that and it doesn't really expose you to how to recognize good designs.

Comment: I think I see the point you are making. In a general sense, the various types of aging LED fixtures that our theatre contain break in one way or another. Management have no intention of replacing these so the challenge becomes seeing what has failed and attempting to replace.
But this may have reached the point at which this is no longer feasible or counter productive.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You might be able to properly dim these LED fixtures - does the spec sheet for the fixture allow you to do this?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly then the fixture does allow for this. The intended operation is for this light to receive a DMX512 signal and smoothly dim throughout all ranges from 0% to 100%.

Comment: OK - yes I missed the word "not" in my previous comment. You could try adding a light-valued load resistor across the LEDs. Now I can't tell you what value to use because I don't know what the maximum output voltage is and what current is taken at this voltage so, if you can find out?

Comment: I will investigate to see if there are any existing load resistors and also voltage/current specs. Thank you

Comment: Do we know the specs of this converter?  If it were me, I'd replace it with something similar.  Should be able to do that inexpensively.

Comment: On a broader scope this makes sense to replace the entire power supply but like-for-like replacements don't seem available from my googling and I have very specific requirements regarding size and shape in order to remount back into the light's enclosure.

Comment: Model: RRT24V402A, 24V, 4.16A, 100W. 4 channels of 12 LEDs that use 500mA each.
I was hoping the symptoms provided may point to an obvious weak link in the circuit but I fear the answer is much more complicated and leaves me contemplating whether its a path I'm committed to pursuing.